# JQuery $('.menu').has('.sub-menu').addClass('has-sub') not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a new class to an element if it has "sub-menu" class. But it is not working. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.menu').has('.sub-menu').addClass('has-sub');
});
```

However, it is working when I remove the .addClass() function and use the .has() function in if statement. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('.menu').has('.sub-menu')) {
       console.log('it's working');
    }
});
```

I think the problem is with .addClass() function, but despite several tries, I am unable to set it right. So please help me with this guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.menu').children('.sub-menu').addClass('has-sub');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work but only if you have one element with class menu, if you have multiple elements you need to make a loop ($.each) and run more tests

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if($('.menu').has('.sub-menu')) {
           $('.menu').addClass('has-sub');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if($('.menu').has('.sub-menu')) {
           $(".sub-menu").addClass('lol');
        }
    });
```